# Postgres ODBC compilation on Windows without openssl dependency

Tags: windows, postgresql, odbc, postgresql-9.5

How to do Postgres ODBC driver compilation on Windows(postgres 9.5.4) without openssl dependency, tried using https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/win32-compilation.html document,but unable to connect to database without any error message. observed wireshark logs but there is no connection in that logs.Please help.

Comment: Are you able to build the ODBC driver without OpenSSL?

Comment: compiled postgres without openssl dependency, and added that path to ODBC compilation through visual studio, without adding the OpenSSL path, and generated psqlodbc35w.dll file which is not connecting to my postgres database while testing.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's going wrong and where.